# Creating Razor radio buttons with AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-declarative-helpers

I currently have a Razor view the makes an AJAX (getJSON) call. The Ajax call requests a list of schools that work with us and "append" the data to a @Html.DropDownListFor called schoolID.

```
$.getJSON('/Account/ajaxGetSchools', function (result) {

    SchoolID.empty();
    $(result).each(function () {
        SchoolID.append(
            $('<option/>', {
                value: this.Id
            }).html(this.Nome)
        );

    });
```

My new requirement is to replace the dropdownlist with dynamically created radio buttons.

This would be easy if i simply used html controls. I would create a group of input-radios. But this seems sloppy from a razor-model-binding paradigm. But I don't think I can make @Html.RadioButton calls within JS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: One option would be to have the ajax call return a partial view that you build using the Html.RadioButton Razor syntax.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness thats an interesting angle. I would guess the partial takes a model with a list of radio-button-data types. Would I use JS to create and populate the model? What if I already have a view populated with a tightly bound model? From what I've noticed multiple models clash.

Comment: You would invoke an Action on the controller that returns a partial view. You would, however, need to parse the fields returned in the main action because of the dynamic nature of the RadioButtons.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness, tell me if I'm on the right track with this: I create my model in the controller (its a query anyway) and bind the new model to the partial. The only thing I'm still concerned about is that the partials' controls will bind to its own model instead of the main views model.

Comment: It can bind, because in the end, it's just rendered by javascript, so there should be no conflict of models. The only challenge is posting back the main view, since parts of it will be dynamic.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness I did with html controls first and now im adopting a partial view approach. Would you like to add it as an official answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to have the AJAX call return a partial view that you build using the Html.RadioButton Razor syntax.

When the main form submits, you can then just parse the input for the radio button values you inserted dynamically.

Comment: I've started to use partials more and more. Now I've refactored to using helpers for this so I can pass variable names and radio defaults
+++